# How to use same font for every file type in emeditor?

Tags: emeditor

my css and txt files use different font ,see below,

how to  use same font  for every file type ?

thanks!

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found answer here: https://www.emeditor.org/en/faq_view_view_different_fonts.html

Q. Different fonts are used when opening different files, or the font used for a new file is different. How can I always use the same font?

Select "**Properties for All Configurations**" on the "**Tools**" menu, select the "**Display**" page, click the "**Font**" button, and the "**Customize Font**" dialog box appears. Click the "**Select All**" button, and click the "**Change**" button in the "**Display Font**" box, and select the font you want to use.